# Database Query based on month

Tags: django

views.py

```
def KEBReading2(request,date=None):
   dates={"Jan":01,"Feb":02,"March":03,"April":04,"May":05,"June":06,"July":07}
   if date in dates:
      a=dates[date]
      print a  
      q1=KEBReading.objects.filter().values()
      print q1.voltage
```

in my databse date is stored in the format YYYY-MM-DD and in my modelforms it is MM/DD/YYYY.
I want to query based on the month. how do i get the entries for the each month from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query the month from your database you can do:

```
q1=KEBReading.objects.filter(somedatefield__month=month)
```

So you can try something like:

```
def KEBReading2(request,date=None):
   dates={"Jan":01,"Feb":02,"March":03,"April":04,"May":05,"June":06,"July":07}
   if date in dates:
      a=dates[date]
      print a  
      q1=KEBReading.objects.filter(somedatefield__month=a).values()
      print q1.voltage
```

If you want the year:

```
q1=KEBReading.objects.filter(somedatefield__year=year)
```

For more, you can refer to the [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/).

Now, if you want to format dates to `MM/DD/YYYY` you can use [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime):

```
>>> print q1.somedatefield.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
'02/01/2013'
```

Comment: but samedatefield_month has format yyyy--mm--dd. so by giving somedatefield_month=a how will it compare. it gives me a error "expected string or buffer". is there a way to split the month field or so?

Comment: How are defining your models? Isn't that field DateTimeField or DateField?

Comment: Update your question. Show how you are doing it and also please show the traceback error

Comment: in the databse the date filed is stored as 2012-03-02. how do i guery in the views to get all the entries with a specific month

Comment: It's in the answer. Say your model `KEBReading` has a `DateTimeField` call `dtf`. If you want all entries with a specific month like December for example: `KEBReading.objects.filter(dtf__month=12)`